# TChart axis labels overlapping when using a lot (more than 100) of TLineSeries

Tags: delphi, teechart

I'm dealing with an application that abuses TChart with potentially hundreds of TLineSeries. I get unreadable X axis labels, because they overlap. According to [this](https://www.steema.com/support/faq/NewVCL/FAQ_VCL_AXES.htm), that shouldn't happen, but it does.

I'm now looking for a way to completely disable X axis labels derived from the TLineSeries elements and only show calculated labels at regular intervals, e.g. no labels for individual data points. How would I do that?

The misbehaving application:

[image]

My failed attempt to replicate the problem:

[image]

Comment: A [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and image showing the issue would help.

Comment: Brian, thanks for taking an interest. I'll try to come up with a test case. Trying to create one actually gave me a potential clue: the program I'm dealing with for some reason overrides the Update method of the form and does a lot of non-drawing work there. This smells... fishy.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot ? Did your chart have min / max value ? Did your series always have the same number of points ?

Comment: @Bosshoss I have added a screenshot that shows the problem. After comparing with my attempt of a minimal test case (which worked), the difference I see are the lines from data points to the X axis. I have looked through the Chart editor and can't find the setting to turn these off. I'm reasonably sure that this is the problem...

Comment: Normally TChart manage X axis to have something that you can read, as your second exemple

Comment: The first comment asked you to provide a [MCVE]. The link takes you to a Stack Overflow help page with the header **Minimal Reproducible Example** Please note the word **Reproducible**. You have supplied two images that shows the problem in the first image but not in the second. But you have not provided any code or property settings with which we can reproduce the erroneous behaviour. Please provide that.

Comment: On the other hand, as you now have two versions, one that produces the unwanted behavior and one that produces the wanted behavior, it should be easy to compare property settings and find the one you need to set correctly.

Comment: @TomBrunberg As I wrote, I haven't been able to come up with a way to reproduce the problem. The code I'm wrestling with isn't exactly readable or well documented. I provided what I could at the moment, which was the asked for screenshots.

Comment: Once again, you were requested for a [mre], which includes *relevant parts of a `.pas` file*, a *`.dfm`* file and an *image* to show the appearance. The reason to the unwanted behavior is most likely revealed by the `object Chart1: TChart` section in the `.dfm` file, unless there is some code in the `.pas` file that forces the unreadable output at the bottom of the chart. If you edit your post to include a reproducible case of what I have requested, I will answer your question.

Comment: @TomBrunberg I really appreciate your willingness to help. It's just not easy at all because the application is highly proprietary, so I have to first find a way to reproduce the problem without copying the whole thing. The original author left late last year, so please bear with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to reproduce the problem with a small test case. Turns out that the problem was, that the application used `function TChartSeries.AddXY(Const AXValue, AYValue: TChartValue; Const ALabel: String; AColor: TColor): Integer;` and provided a value for `ALabel`. Using only X and Y values fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the Bottom Axis for the chart has a scale set with Automatic turned off (default is on) you can get overlap like that depending on your data, the desired increment and if Show all labels is checked.

However your example seems to show non-regular extra labels which might just be manually added using the Items (show in far right tab) or something else to add more axis labels.

[image]